# Get tuple list in python with Xpath

Tags: python, list, xpath, tuples

I would like to get a tuple list using xpath in python, for example:

```
page = requests.get('url')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
list_a = tree.xpath('//div[@class="a"]/text()')
list_b = tree.xpath('//div[@class="b"]/text()')
```

list_a and list_b should be combined to a unique list so each elements of the same index form a tuple.

Maybe I could do it by manipulating both lists but I prefer to get directly the list of tuples with one call to xpath if this is possible.

Comment: So you want to `zip`?

Comment: Yes by manipulating both lists but this implies that I make two calls of xpath.

Answer (score 1):

You can first fetch the list of elements with:

```
result = tree.xpath('//div[@class="a" or @class="b"]/text()')
```

which will generate a list of *elements* that match one of the two constraints. Next we can `zip` them together with:

```
result = iter(result)
result = list(zip(result,result))
```

This does **one call to `xpath`**, and then uses some post-processing to obtain the tuples. Note that if two `<td class="a">` tags occur before a `<td class="b">` tag, they will be packed into one tuple. So it is important that the `<td class="a">` and `<td class="b">` are **interleaved**.

Answer (score 0):

use OR in xpath

```
tree.xpath('//div[@class="a"]/text() | //div[@class="b"]/text()')
```

Comment: Could you be more precise ? This returns a list of tuples as I expect ?